# How To/Resources on configuring Openfire with its built-in Bosh support to accept XMPP chat client?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

Know of any tutorials or resources to configure Openfire Server to use it's built in Bosh support for an XMPP chat client developed with stroph.  The Openfire Server is an existing company chat server used with Spark and Pidgin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install openfire, its bosh service starts listening on a port (I think its 5080), when you try to access bosh using strpohe, normal javascript will not allow you to access strophe because javascript is not permitted to access ports, you either have to use proxy module or url redirect, if you are not good at apache configuration you can use flxhr javascript plugin. For tutorial you can use Metajack's http://professionalxmpp.com/.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using the flxhr plugin. I'm also using the gab chat application in Metajack's book.  Should I try changing the Strophe.Connection from 'http: //bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind/' to 'http: //myservername:5080/xmpp-httpbind'?

Comment: Yes change it to http: //myservername:5080/xmpp-httpbind or http: //myservername:5080/http-bind

Comment: yes that helps. i had the wrong port number.  so one should make sure they check their server for the right port number (binding port is diff from server port).

Comment: Openfire uses port 7070 for unsecured HTTP connections by default. For secured connections 7443 is used.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-realtimeXMPPtut/section4.html

Great article covering server and client apps.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  I got it to work with the flash plugin (flxHR), but now I'd like to do something like this article using a reverse proxy but with IIS.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use IIS and another proxy server to achieve this result? (and how)